# Notification when users are changing their informations

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I want to notify the administrator when the user change his profile (for example, change his pseudo, his avatar and other custom fields attached to the user(People > Account settings > Add a new field) )

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the perfect module for this would be [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) . There is a lot of docu on the project page.

- Event:

  - Create a new rule on event **user update**
- Condition

  - add condition (check for modifications..)
- Result

  - trigger email

Comment: I'll check that tomorrow but it looks like an awersome module !

Comment: Beautifull! I've added the (email == oldemail)NOT to launch the email, works good ! Thans to make me use that module, he's very usefull!